# Is it possible to run multiple stages in a parallel branch in a scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Based on this [article](http://jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/), you can do this in a declarative pipeline. I was wondering if it can be done in a scripted one. We've gotten one stage to run in parallel but I can't get more than one to run in a scripted pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
stage("single step before") {
    echo "this is a single step before"
}

stage("parallel tasks") {
    parallel 'pipe1': {
        stage("parallel 1"){
            echo "pipe1: this is parallel 1"
        }
        stage("parallel 2"){
            echo "pipe1: this is parallel 2"
        }
        stage("parallel 3"){
            echo "pipe1: this is parallel 3"
        }
    }, 'parallel 4': {
        echo "pipe2: this is parallel 4"
    }
}

stage("single step after") {
    echo "this is a single step after"
}
```